# Trying to access a object property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Hi I got a question about the following screenshot link: http://i.imgur.com/BpUzUvU.png

I want to access the `user` object with the property `team`. I had already tried `data.Object` but that gives me an undefined output.

And I had already tried `data.user` but that gives me the following output:
screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StGVh.png

Comment: It doesn't look like the `user` object has a `team` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.team is the answer. And I was a bit sleepy over there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var team = server.game.join.team.team;
var user = server.game.join.team.user;

// extend user for team
user['team'] = team;
```